# Execution policy exception registration failed and was skipped: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-ios

I have an ionic app and I'm trying to run this:

```
ionic cordova build ios
```

Compilation succeeds, but I see these errors just before it succeeds:

```
RegisterExecutionPolicyException /Users/moblizeit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Scan_Buddy-bgqkrrwvotqcxbgakwtfvdcnmkvx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Scan\ Buddy/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Scan\ Buddy.app (in target 'Scan Buddy' from project 'Scan Buddy')
    cd /Users/moblizeit/code-repo/apps/business-card-scanner/businesscardscanner/platforms/ios
    builtin-RegisterExecutionPolicyException /Users/moblizeit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Scan_Buddy-bgqkrrwvotqcxbgakwtfvdcnmkvx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Scan\ Buddy/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Scan\ Buddy.app
note: Execution policy exception registration failed and was skipped: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted" (in target 'Scan Buddy' from project 'Scan Buddy')
```

Any idea about what is failing and how to fix it?

Comment: Seems to be a Catalina problem - https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/124529.  Maybe safe to ignore?

Comment: @Moblize I have the same problem, is there a chance you manage to solve it?

Comment: I have open an issue [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/832) to see if this can be a problem from the cordova-ios.

Comment: If you pass `UseModernBuildSystem=NO` to xcodebuild or change this setting in your xcode project from `File` -> `Project Settings...` -> `Build System` drop down to `Legacy Build System` will remove the error. I don't think this is the "correct" solution though.

Comment: I get the same thing and I'm NOT running ionic (straight Cordova) so it's not isolated to the ionic CLI. @Hermang's issue on apache/cordova-cli was fairly specific to passing parameters to ionic, but I'm not doing that so my experience is every so slightly different. We'll see if Apple barks during approval though, that should hint if it's important or not.

Comment: It could very well be the name of your app - even in the file structure itself, try renaming it to ScanBuddy perhaps? I believe the space is causing the issue.

Comment: Just a wild suggestion and ignore me if I am stupid but what happens if you change your project folder name to not include a white-space, so something like `Scan_Buddy`