# Why does my Podspec throws multiple: "Execution policy exception registration failed and was skipped" notes?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, xcodebuild, podspec

Podspec is:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
    s.name             = 'MyPod'
    s.version          = '0.1.0'
    s.summary          = 'my summary.'
    s.platform         = :ios, '13.0'
    s.description      = <<-DESC
  My description.
                         DESC
    s.homepage         = 'https://github.com/MyAccount/MyPod'
    s.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
    s.author           = { 'Me' => 'my@email.com' }
    s.source           = { :git => 'https://github.com/MyAccount/MyPod.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }
    s.swift_version    = '5.0'
    s.source_files     = 'MyPod/Classes/**/*'
    s.static_framework = true

    s.dependency 'Firebase'
    s.dependency 'Firebase/Core'
    s.dependency 'Firebase/Auth'
    s.dependency 'Firebase/Database'
    s.dependency 'GoogleSignIn'
    s.dependency 'GoogleAPIClientForREST/Core'
    s.dependency 'GoogleAPIClientForREST/Sheets'
    s.dependency 'GTMAppAuth'
  end
```

(`MyPod` etc are stand-ins for actual Pod name)

`pod lib lint MyPod.podspec` produces:

```
 -> MyPod (0.1.0)
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  note: Using new build system
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Planning build
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Constructing build description
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Execution policy exception registration failed and was skipped: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted" (in target 'nanopb' from project 'Pods')
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Execution policy exception registration failed and was skipped: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted" (in target 'GoogleUtilities' from project 'Pods')
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Execution policy exception registration failed and was skipped: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted" (in target 'GoogleDataTransport' from project 'Pods')
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Execution policy exception registration failed and was skipped: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted" (in target 'leveldb-library' from project 'Pods')
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Execution policy exception registration failed and was skipped: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted" (in target 'GTMSessionFetcher' from project 'Pods')
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Execution policy exception registration failed and was skipped: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted" (in target 'GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport' from project 'Pods')
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Execution policy exception registration failed and was skipped: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted" (in target 'AppAuth' from project 'Pods')
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Execution policy exception registration failed and was skipped: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted" (in target 'FirebaseCoreDiagnostics' from project 'Pods')
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Execution policy exception registration failed and was skipped: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted" (in target 'GTMAppAuth' from project 'Pods')
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Execution policy exception registration failed and was skipped: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted" (in target 'GoogleAPIClientForREST' from project 'Pods')
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Execution policy exception registration failed and was skipped: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted" (in target 'FirebaseCore' from project 'Pods')
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Execution policy exception registration failed and was skipped: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted" (in target 'FirebaseInstanceID' from project 'Pods')
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Execution policy exception registration failed and was skipped: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted" (in target 'FirebaseDatabase' from project 'Pods')
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Execution policy exception registration failed and was skipped: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted" (in target 'FirebaseAuth' from project 'Pods')
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Execution policy exception registration failed and was skipped: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted" (in target 'MyPod' from project 'Pods')
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Execution policy exception registration failed and was skipped: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted" (in target 'Pods-App' from project 'Pods')
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Execution policy exception registration failed and was skipped: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted" (in target 'App' from project 'App')
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  warning: Skipping code signing because the target does not have an Info.plist file and one is not being generated automatically. (in target 'App' from project 'App')

MyPod passed validation.
```

Environment:

```
CocoaPods version: 1.8.4
Operating System: Catalina 10.15.1 Beta 
Xcode version: 11.2
```

(I am aware of the similar question: [Execution policy exception registration failed and was skipped: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58686708/execution-policy-exception-registration-failed-and-was-skipped-error-domain-nsp))

---

**ADDENDUM**

I just tried making a very plain Pod including the default dependency `AFNetworking` that is included (if commented out) in the .podspec file that is created by running `pod lib create MyPod`. Produces the same result:

```
 -> MyOtherPod (0.1.0)
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  note: Using new build system
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Planning build
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Constructing build description
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Execution policy exception registration failed and was skipped: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted" (in target 'AFNetworking' from project 'Pods')
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Execution policy exception registration failed and was skipped: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted" (in target 'MyOtherPod' from project 'Pods')
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Execution policy exception registration failed and was skipped: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted" (in target 'Pods-App' from project 'Pods')
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Execution policy exception registration failed and was skipped: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted" (in target 'App' from project 'App')
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  warning: Skipping code signing because the target does not have an Info.plist file and one is not being generated automatically. (in target 'App' from project 'App')
```

Comment: Do you have an `info.plist` file that is properly configured in your pod's build settings? `NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  warning: Skipping code signing because the target does not have an Info.plist file and one is not being generated automatically. (in target 'App' from project 'App')`

Comment: Thank you for the comment @CodeBender I haven't had time to check this since, but I hope your suggestion is useful to others

Comment: I made a comment on how to let it go away in your the other linked question https://stackoverflow.com/q/58686708/ but I this is not the root cause to my understanding which is what you're asking for.